# XCode 4 Will Not Let Me Add New Methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been working with xcode 4 for a few months now with no problem, well with some problems but that is another story, and now have a weird problem.  I can not add any new methods...  What I mean to say is when I add a new method xcode doesn't recognize it.  The tag follow doesn't see it and the debugger errors saying there is no method by that name.  However, the method just above it with the exact same signature minus the name works famously.

Has anyone ever seen this before?  If so could you please send me in the right direction.  Any help and I would be eternally grateful.

```
- (void)showMyCalendar:(TKCalendarMonthView*) calendar1
{
        if (calendar1.frame.origin.y == -calendar1.frame.size.height+calendarShadowOffset) 
    {
        [self displayCalendar:calendar1];
    }
    else
    {
        [self hideCalendar:calendar1];
    }
    [self showMyCalendar:calendar1]; // If I put a call here xcode sees it.
}


- (void)anotherMethod:(TKCalendarMonthView*) calendar1
{
        if (calendar1.frame.origin.y == -calendar1.frame.size.height+calendarShadowOffset) 
    {
        [self displayCalendar:calendar1];
    }
    else
    {
        [self hideCalendar:calendar1];
    }
    [self showMyCalendar:calendar1]; // If I put a call here xcode DOES NOT see it.
}
```

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: can you post bits of your code please

Comment: Please provide your method declaration as well as the implementation.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, more to this question... Perhaps I am just not well versed in Objective C...  am calling it via [self method-name]  and within the method itself it sees it but within another method it does not...  Most likely there is a simple explanation but I am surely in the dark.  Please advise.

Comment: If you declared the method in the .h file, it should be visible to other objects.  If you declared it within the .m file, it is not visible to other objects.

Comment: Please do not put your code in comments, edit your original question and add them there (using the code formatting functions too please)

Comment: Compared to Xcode 3, Xcode 4 really sucks.  It's a lot fussier and also tends to get "confused" more often.  Sometimes you have to delete the "derived data" and let Xcode recreate it to straighten things up.  Other times it seems you must simply ditch the project and start over from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the "derived data"!  Could you please tell me how to do that?  I have cleaned the project but that hasn't helped...  Is there some other place where the derived data exists? Thanks to all for putting up with my bad posting.  I am new to this board :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include a method definition in your .h file for the .m file that this method is contained in?

```
- (void)anotherMethod:(TKCalendarMonthView*) calendar1;
```

Comment: OK got it!  I didn't think you had to do that if within the same file.  Jeremy actually answered this a bit earlier as well.

Comment: You actually don't have to do that as long as they're in the same file... **if** you're using the LLVM Compiler in Xcode 4.3. New feature.

Comment: Hmm, Xcode 4.3. I am using 4.2. Perhaps an upgrade is in order.  Many thanks to all for your assistance.!